# How make fancybox working with symfony framework?

Tags: frameworks, fancybox, symfony-1.4

I am using symfony 1.4. I would like to ask you for a help with fancy box. How can i make that fancy gallery after click on my image. Please.

Well i tried do something like that:
in apps/fronted/config/viey.yml

```
javascripts:    [jquery-1.4.3.min.js, jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js]
```

also put that files in css folder web/js

in apps/fronted/config/templates/layout.php i leave it with no changes

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//PL" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="pl" lang="pl">
 <head>
        <?php include_http_metas() ?>
        <?php include_metas() ?>
        <?php include_title() ?>
        <?php include_stylesheets() ?>
        <?php include_javascripts() ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div class="content">
                <?php echo $sf_content ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

in apps/fronted/modules/myshop/templates/homeSuccess.php i wrote

```
<a id="single_image" href="images/braceles/1.jpg">
<img src="images/braceles/1.jpg" alt=""/></a>
```

after that i click on image, it redirect me to page with image instead that fancy view :( i don't get it, what is that "single_image" and what do i do wrong?
Please help me, thanks user! :)

Comment: You can't just add the FancyBox js, you need to [tell FancyBox which elements you want to apply it to](http://fancybox.net/howto) (see section 5).

Comment: @Alex i tried add own js, and also write script in layout with no success. I added all files to js folder and wrote in view.yml

Comment: Are you getting any errors the JavaScript console?

Comment: javascript console? hmm i have never use any debugger for pages. it's my first site.

Comment: Use Firefox, install Firebug, right click the page, use Firebug, click the console tab. Refresh the page, see if any errors appear in the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  use fansybox like :
**In apps/fronted/config/view.yml**

```
javascripts: [jquery-1.6.2.min.js,fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js,fancybox/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js,fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js,fancybox/fancyconfig.js]
stylesheets:    [fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css]
```

**In my fancyconfig.js**

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $("a#image_fancybox").fancybox({
                'titlePosition'     : 'over',
                'overlayOpacity'    : 0.4
            });

});
```

In my **apps/fronted/modules/mymod/templates/indexSuccess.php**

```
<a id="image_fancybox" title="<?php echo $project->getDescription()?>" href="<?php echo "/uploads/projects/".$project->getImage() ?>"> <img src="<?php echo "/uploads/projects/thumbnails/thumb_".$project->getImage() ?>" alt="<?php echo $project->getDescription() ?>"/></a>
```

So, it is work. You can use [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) in [firefox](http://www.mozilla.org/) , that debug you js code.

Comment: i found out, this project would run with jquery if it has htaccess file in web folder and in main directory.. I am running it on W7. So the problem is solved, but why it needs htacces ??

Comment: I not too sure why you've set this as the answer, as it doesn't give you the solution you required. I suspect you required a proper `.htaccess` in order to stop requests to the javascript files being directed to Symfony.

Comment: @Alex your answer was the same as mine, and you are right this should be the answer by the way